# How to update a collection in the controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How can I update a User's stores when I'm passing a collection from the form? I don't want to add the store if the User already has it, and I also want to be able to remove the store from the User if the user un-checkmarks the checkbox in the form.

My Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, :url => user_stores_path, method: :post, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :stores, as: :check_boxes, include_hidden: false, label: false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Update Favorite Stores", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My Models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stores
  has_many :stores, through: :user_stores        
end

class UserStore < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stores
  has_many :users, through: :user_stores
end
```

My UserController:

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @stores = Store.find(params[:user][:store_ids])
    @stores.each do |store|
      @user.stores << store // How can I skip over if the user already has the store in the collection or if a store has been removed
    end
    redirect to user_stores_path(@user)
end
```

Comment: hmm you probably don't need to fetch the stores.  just try `@user.store_ids = params[:user][:store_ids]` and then `@user.save`.  Rails should take care of creating the records

Comment: @jvnill What if `params[:user][:store_ids]` contains invalid ids?

Comment: @codeignitor I'm not sure what the behavior will be.  `Store.find(array_of_ids)` will raise an exception if at least one of the ids is not in the db.

Comment: I may be confused but shouldn't you be using update instead of create if stores already exist?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss The reason why is because I am using nested routes, resources store is nested inside of resources user. The route that seemed most accurate is user_stores_path which goes to `/user/:user_id/stores` which is a `Post` for `stores#create`. If I used update, it would be `user_store_path` which goes to `/user/:user_id/stores/:id` which is a `Patch` for `stores#update`. However I don't have a specific store I'm updating, I'm updating/creating store_ids (a collection), which is an array of store ids that I want the user to have (creating entries in the join table).That was my thinking.